# Restricting websites through Registry Editor applies in Internet Explorer, however site is not blocked

Tags: windows, windows-registry, internet-explorer

I've successfully created keys in this path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains`

I then added a DWORD named `*` with a value of `4`. This adds the key into the Restricted Sites zone in Internet Explorer. The problem is that even though I can literally see the site in the restricted sites zone of Internet Explorer, I can still navigate to it.

Comment: "d-word" ? What?

Comment: @harrymc "A DWORD value, which stands for Double Word, is one of the five main data types handled by the Registry Editor. A DWORD value can hold a maximum of 32 bits." - [source](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-add-a-new-dword-in-regedit)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are misunderstanding the purpose of the *Restricted sites* zone. This is not a list of websites that are completely blocked. Instead, it's a list of websites with restricted features.

If you click the *Custom level…* button, you can see what can be restricted on those websites.

From [Microsoft](http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-c9a5706f-0596-424f-bdfa-59618cb136e2/):

> Websites that might damage files and your PC should be assigned to this zone. Adding sites to the Restricted zone doesn't block them, but it prevents them from using scripting or any active content (interactive or animated content on websites). The security level for Restricted sites is set to High and can't be changed.

Comment: I see, however if I manually add any site to the restricted zone, the browser will not navigate to it. I am looking for that same behaviour. Is it possible?

Comment: I can't replicate that. For me, the sites still load, they just load without JavaScript.